# What English/Latin proportion should we have in our introductory tour?

Tags: discussion, introductory-tour

And more specifically: should it be only English, or should it have Latin parts, or a link to some Latin mirror? If there is some "mirror tour", should it be the tour translated as-is, slightly changed, or completely different?

This might be somewhat connected with our policy for [welcoming those who understand Latin well but only a little English](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/65/52). I can imagine a Latin paragraph welcoming Latin speakers, explaining the minimum understanding of English required etc.

Comment: Note that most parts of the tour are fixed, and thus inevitably are in English. There are some parts that moderators can edit, e.g., the introduction, but if we want a complete Latin tour, we would have to create it separately, e.g., on Meta.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: I didn|t know that. Edited to reflect the real state of things.

Answer (score 5):

I think the introduction tour should be in English.
Some of the example questions can be fully in Latin, but not all.
The tour is targeted for English-speaking new users since it is largely fixed to have English content anyway.

To welcome users who don't understand English, we should create an introduction and instruction page in Latin.
That page could be less detailed and give links to the English tour and help pages for deeper information.
I don't know how such a Latin page could be created, though.

At the moment I would suggest asking a meta question "How to use this site?" (or similar) in Latin, and then the answers would cover different sides of the functionality.