# Should all-Latin answers be permitted?

Tags: discussion, site-policy, answers

As a companion to [Should all-Latin questions be permitted?](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/should-all-latin-questions-be-permitted), the same policy regarding answers is probably worth considering separately.  (brianpck even provides a handy [example of an all-Latin answer](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13/21) to that same question.)

Many of the same considerations apply as with all-Latin questions, but I think they're worth thinking about and debating separately.  For me, personally, as one relatively Latin-illiterate, if I hit an all-Latin question I'll probably just skip over it without much of a reaction. However, if I encounter an all-Latin answer to a question I'm interested in, not being able to understand it is actively *irritating*.

*Related:

[Should all-Latin question **titles** be permitted?](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66/should-all-latin-question-titles-be-permitted)*

Comment: Related answer here: http://meta.latin.stackexchange.com/a/70/16

Comment: My referenced answer actually includes a quasi-answer to this question: in Latin, I wrote at the end: "However, I don't think that it is a good idea to offer an [exclusively] Latin answer to someone asking in English." That seems to defeat the purpose of the Q&A

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Write your answer in a way that you think would be most helpful for the person who asked the question.**

That's how it works on all StackExchange sites. As for whether to answer in all English, all Latin, a mix, or to bring in other languages, let's have **no rule**—and no finger-wagging, scolding, or "discouraging". Let's leave that choice to the judgement of the person writing the answer. We have upvotes and downvotes to let the community render an opinion one answer at a time.

**Levels of writing**

We can probably learn something from another successful StackExchange site, [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/). There, people learning English are required to ask all questions *in English* and all answers are in English—even though many of the questioners are still working at a very basic level of English, and their questions frequently contain grammatical errors.

A good answer is written at a *level* of English appropriate to what was demonstrated in the question. Some English constructions, such as those with phrasal verbs,  can be tricky for ESL learners to understand. So, with total beginners, I usually avoid phrases like "get over" or "get into". On the other hand, with some users (like [LePressentiment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/8712/lepressentiment), who is also here), sometimes I intentionally write a little above their level, since I know they're ready for it and interested in it. Sometimes that leads to another fruitful question.

**Pictures**

By the way, pictures often help enormously. Here's [a fine example](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/49929/6700) by [J.R.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/113/j-r), one of ELL's leading contributors, that very concisely addresses a subtlety of English grammar that often confuses ESL learners from non-Germanic languages: the way a preposition often follows (rather than precedes) a noun that it's indicating a relation to. This was made for a user who had been struggling with very basic English grammar:

[image: A long heavy chain connecting the steel ball to a ship above.]

In this case, the troublesome preposition is **above**.

Comment: Good answer! It is hereby above mine. P.S. I'm not sure I'd call *above* a preposition any more if it is written after the noun—which is...entirely irrelevant to your post. Oh, well.

Comment: @Cerberus Indeed, the term "preposition" has been causing confusion in English grammar for centuries now. I doubt that we have the power to fix it here. I just call words that _can_ introduce prepositional phrases "prepositions" regardless of their actual function in the sentence.

Comment: You mean we can't fix the Internet in a SE comment??

Answer (score 9):

If the question is in all Latin, then let the answer be in all Latin if the answerer so desires. But, if the question is in English, there is a chance that the questioner will not understand the answer, or not very well, which is a bit impolite.

So I say, let answers be **either in English or in the language of the question, or in Latin with an English translation or summary** (everybody likes summaries...).

The reason why Latin answers may sometimes be desirable is that one often learns a language faster through immersion.

At any rate, I think "permitted" is a bit strong: if someone answers an English question in Latin, he should be encourages to add an English translation, but it should not be "forbidden" i.e. deleted.

Answer (score 5):

If the question is in English, answer in English.  If in Latin, answer in either language.  Translations/summaries are encouraged.

That is:

- If the question is in English only, answer the question in English

  - If desired, include a Latin translation
- If the question is in Latin only, answer the question in Latin **or** English

  - An English translation or summary is encouraged, but if one is not provided, one may be added by someone else in the community.
- If the question, as written by the OP, includes both languages, then answer the question in either or both languages.

Answer (score 1):

**I strongly disagree that we should encourage these.**

As a beginner in Latin - which I think many are - my knowleudge of the language is far from extensive.  I may not understand in full an answer to my question if it is only in Latin.

I'm more supportive of this if the asker requests an all-Latin answer, but this still may not help future readers.

Additionaly, English translations would help in these answers.

Comment: Do you think that only encouraging these to all-Latin questions would be good? Or to encourage, more forcefully, answer posters to provide an English translation?

Comment: @Undo I would suggest we encourage a Latin version and an English translation.

Comment: I am not sure that they're very helpful. No one here is a native speaker and so far some of the Latin questions and answers have been grammatically suspect.

Comment: @C.M.Weiner I'm not saying that we should support them, just that there are cases where they can be tolerated.