# Should all-Latin question *titles* be permitted?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-policy

As yet another twist on the "allow all-Latin content or not" theme, should we permit all-Latin question ***titles***?

On the one hand, an all-Latin question title might serve as an advertisement of sorts for an all-Latin question.  On the other hand, it may discourage the non-Latin fluent from even clicking into the question.  Either of these could be a feature or a bug, depending on the intent of the asker.

*Related:

[Should all-Latin questions be permitted?](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/should-all-latin-questions-be-permitted)

[Should all-Latin answers be permitted?](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64/should-all-latin-answers-be-permitted)*

Comment: You might consider accepting Robert's answer so that it appears above mine. His is better and far more official.

Comment: I don't plan to accept an answer on this one at least until Friday: http://meta.latin.stackexchange.com/questions/19/wait-few-days-before-accepting-answers :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Studying any language has long been known to be best conducted in a full-immersion environment (i.e. in the target language only), so we *encourage* our language sites to **use the target language wherever possible.**

We've even considered (on the Stack Exchange Team) urging our language sites to become *full immersion only,* but since converting the UI to another target langage was much more difficult than anticipated, we've been dragging our heels about suggesting it at all.

But every language site should support (and even *encourage*) the use of the target language wherever folks can type.

**So, yes** — Latin should be allowed in questions, answers, comments, flags, meta posts, documentation, usernames, profiles… *did I forget anything?*

Comment: I actually rather like the idea of a full-immersion approach to this. It'd certainly help me become more fluent in Latin. That said, we'd probably want a way to switch between the Latin and English interface - if for no other reason than to be sure that a button actually says "spam".

Comment: There seem to be [varying opinions](http://meta.latin.stackexchange.com/questions/5/should-all-latin-questions-be-permitted) with respect to the "full-immersion", because Latin is a "dead language", i.e. because there are not enough native speakers. (I'm not doing the argument against full immersion justice here. Please read the relevant answers over on the meta post.)

Comment: I'd like to see the complete UI in Latin! [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook/latin-becomes-a-living-language-on-facebook/145923442130/) already this, though only some parts are in Latin, and some phrases are currently coming out with mistakes. As you probably noticed, switching to a "scrambling" language with noun cases is not a trivial exercise. But whenever it becomes feasible, I welcome it!

Comment: *Latin should be allowed in […] meta posts, […]* – Just checking, before I blow the trumpet: Does this apply to all other language sites as well?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft We used to say if you want us (the Community Team) to be familiar with your community issues, meta posts would have to be in English. But on the rare, rare occasion where this was ever an issue, a post is easily Google-translated. In reality, meta is for the community, so they should post in whichever language is most comfortable for *them.* The reason to try and enforce *"you can post {spanish} everywhere... except meta"*, in my opinion, was too obscure to worry about in actual practice, so I never worried about it.

Comment: @RobertCartaino, does this apply to private beta? I mean, is a private-beta language-learning site allowed to use the target language within meta too?

Comment: @Sasha If you want the Community Team's assistance (by knowing what you are talking about), posts should be in English. We do not force the issue, but keep in mind that the Community Team is your only moderation during the private beta (until pro tems can be appointed), so translation into English seems... wise.

Answer (score 10):

I would consider myself to be very... *not* fluent in Latin. That said, these all-Latin titles (like [Nonne "a fortiori, a priori, a posteriori" solecismi sunt?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/133/nonne-a-fortiori-a-priori-a-posteriori-solecismi-sunt)) actually intrigue me. It's a challenge to read them, but they stand out and I enjoy the challenge. I've actually noticed my fluency improve in the few hours this site has been around, and I believe it's due to the all-Latin posts.

I would recommend providing an English translation of the title in the body if you (as the OP, or as an editor) deem it necessary. However, most people here should be able to read a simple title without much trouble.