# Should our tags be in Latin?

Tags: discussion, tags

On other Stack Exchange language sites, tags and tag wikis are in the language the site uses. French Language, for example, names their tags in French. Currently, Latin Language Stack Exchange has tags in English.

Should we rename our tags to Latin? For example, should [etymology](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymology) because [etymologiam](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymologiam), or some such form of the word?

Comment: Spanish and Portuguese use their respective languages for tags, but [German uses English](https://german.stackexchange.com/tags).

Comment: I'd like to suggest that, if we do this, we use the ablative case (because "de" takes an ablative, and tags describe de quo rogatur.

Comment: Followup discussion from 2021: [What language should our tags be?](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/546/10063)

Answer (score 9):

I was initially against this (from a not-fluent student point of view), but now I think it might be a good idea. Changing our tags to be Latin would fall in nicely with the full immersion approach [that is recommended by SE staff](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/a/70/11). I think it'd help folks like me learn the language.

However, as a student, I'd want liberal (ab)use of synonyms. For your example above, we should make a [etymology](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymology) -> [etymologiam](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymologiam) synonym. This would let me type [english-tag](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/english-tag) into the tag box and get [obscure-latin-tag-that-means-the-same-thing](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/obscure-latin-tag-that-means-the-same-thing) instead.

We'd need people proactively suggesting/creating these, and staff or moderators (when we get our own) approving them. Do we have the resources to do that yet? I'm not sure, but if we're going to do this it'd be best to do it in private beta.

Comment: I support the synonyms thing as well -- it shouldn't be a requirement to know Latin to post here well.

Comment: I think moderators are nominated after about two weeks of private beta and appointed shortly afterwards, which if everything goes well should be near the end of private beta. I've been doing a lot of tag cleaning (as moderator) on Japanese.SE and Portuguese.SE and it's not that much of a deal to put everything in order, even if it is a mess to start with. (As ordinary user, suggesting tag synonyms etc. is a lot more difficult and doesn't really help the moderators, so I'd suggest we leave this job to our moderators.)

Comment: @Earthliŋ Suggesting tag synonyms *does* help moderators: they have a dashboard where they can see suggestions. However, only existing tags can be voted on, the direction is imposed by quantity rather than policy, and the requirements exclude most users. *Voting* on tag synonyms is pretty pointless because in practice there are never enough voters.

Comment: For the private beta, I suggest making a meta thread with a list of desired synonyms. By the time the site has mods, ping a moderator in chat if you see a missing synonym.

Comment: @Gilles OK, but having a list of synonyms is just as helpful as a "tag synonym" suggested by a user. The tag synonym is without any comments/discussion, so you'd have to go back to the meta post anyway to see if X → Y is in fact what the community wants the moderator to implement. In this sense tag synonyms suggested as such (in the system) are pretty useless. All I really wanted to say is that there's little an ordinary user can do to help clean up tags other than take an active part in the discussion about tag synonyms on meta.

Answer (score 9):

I <sup><sub>(grudgingly)</sub></sup> admit that in the long run Latin tags will be a better option than English.  But I'm concerned that saying "Latin tags only" is going to hamstring our efforts to fully tag the questions that we get.

To put it simply: We are going to need *a lot* more tags than the ones we have now.  And if we say, "no new English tags," then many people won't be able to fully participate in that effort.

I'm more comfortable if we understand that the end goal is that all tags be in Latin, with English synonyms, but that we will achieve that goal through the combined efforts of those less comfortable with Latin (what's the Latin for [enclitic](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enclitic), anyway?) who create tags in English, and those more comfortable with Latin, who kindly retag with the Latin version and synonymize.

And yes, we need synonyms.  Lots and lots of them.

Comment: Once we have moderators they will be able to deal with English tags swiftly, by making them synonymous to a Latin translation. The retagging of English tags to their Latin synonyms happens automatically. In other words, it doesn't really matter if we start out with a healthy mix of Latin and English tags. We just need to decide on a translation (probably best discussed in a meta post).

Comment: @Earthliŋ We're on the same page, I think.  A healthy mix of Latin and English tags is great, and over time the more Latin-saavy contributors can hash out the best translations for the English ones, at which point the mods can make the English ones mere synonyms

Comment: On [french.se], we have a policy of having French tags with English synonyms. I think all language sites should do this.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think this is a good idea. It works for other languages because the primary purpose of those languages is current communication *in* those languages. The primary purpose of Latin and other dead languages is instead to understand written texts.

Given that this is an English site and that the people who primarily come here know English, I can see zero benefit is making the tags Latin. In fact, despite Ben Kovitz' idea of mods tagging posts, one of the main purposes of tags is to allow users to explore efficiently. That purpose is wholly defeated if we resort to esoteric language and possibly made up words for which the ancient Romans had nothing comparable.

Editing this to incorporate [Earthliŋ's comments](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80/should-our-tags-be-in-latin#comment193_84), which I wholeheartedly agree with. I think this would make an excellent compromise:

> Something that we did on Japanese.SE is to use English tags, but give a Japanese translation right at the beginning of the tag excerpt ([picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXsGY.png)). This way the tags are easier to type and recognize, but hovering over them reveals the translation straight away. We could decide whether we want to include pseudo-Latin translations for modern words, but at least they won't feature as strongly and we would have the most useful/widely-known terminology on the tag itself. This might be a "best of both worlds"...?

Edited again just to keep the conversation going. Can someone chime in, one way or another?

Comment: Something that we did on Japanese.SE is to use English tags, but give a Japanese translation right at the beginning of the tag excerpt ([picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RXsGY.png)). This way the tags are easier to type and recognize, but hovering over them reveals the translation straight away. We could decide whether we want to include pseudo-Latin translations for modern words, but at least they won't feature as strongly and we would have the most useful/widely-known terminology on the tag itself. This might be a "best of both worlds"...?

Answer (score 6):

### Yes

I think naming the tags in Latin is a great idea! It's an easy, convenient way to pick up a little more Latin by *using it* rather than just talking about it.

Happily, people just starting Latin don't need to know what the tag words mean, because more-experienced users can add and edit the tags on questions. Experienced users on most StackExchanges normally do most of the tagging.

However, there is one difficulty: when first-time users post a first question, they may be perplexed and put off by the need to supply a tag. Any ideas for a solution? Can we have the software suggest a tag? I probably shouldn't suggest [grammatica](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammatica), but the English version of that enabled me to get started with my first question.

Comment: If you type in "grammar" as a tag on Spanish when asking a question, it auto-suggests "gramática" and shows that "grammar" is a synonym.

Comment: @Nathaniel That sounds like the ideal solution.

Comment: Yes, see my answer. We can create 'synonyms', which make the system automatically suggest (and forcefully replace) English tags with Latin tags.