# The tags [ovid] and [ovidius] are not marked as synonyms

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Currently, the tag [ovidius](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ovidius) has five questions, and the tag [ovid](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ovid) has one question. The questions are clearly about the same author (and there is only one famous poem named Ovid, as far as I know). [ovid](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ovid) is not marked as a synonym of [ovidius](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ovidius) (or *vice versa*). It shouldn't be difficult to choose a canonical tag and mark the other one as a synonym. What do you think?

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up, and good to see you on the forum!

Answer (score 7):

Thank you for noticing!
We have [discussed author tags on meta before](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/109/79), and we concluded that they should be in the original Latin form.
This has been our policy both *de facto* and *de iure*.

Therefore I went ahead and marked [ovid](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ovid) as a synonym of [ovidius](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ovidius), leaving [ovidius](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ovidius) as the main tag.
Having English or other forms of the tags as synonyms is fine, as it may help some find the author they want, so I would not forcibly remove them.

(If there are disagreements about synonyms, they can always be undone. A moderator's word need not be final.)

Comment: That was quick :-)

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe, I am sometimes quick. :o) Oh, and thanks for the recent tag wiki edit suggestions; I accepted them with minor modifications.

Comment: Make sure you merge the tags together if no disagreements ever arise. :) (Not merging *probably* won't cause major problems on a smaller site that's still growing, but can cause quite a bit of confusion on larger sites. It's just a good habit.)