# Potential questions to be tagged as `genus-epistula`?

Tags: support, tags

A few days ago I suggested the tag [genus-epistula](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/genus-epistula) and (unfortunately caused an issue when I) went on to tag all questions I could find that clearly belonged under that tag. There were a few questions which I was unsure of whether should get the new tag, and I believe it was Joonas who suggested I ask this in meta.

**Should the following questions be tagged as `genus-epistula`?**

- [Did “benedicere” ever mean “to blaspheme”?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/9133/did-benedicere-ever-mean-to-blaspheme)
  Letter-writing is relevant, but not key to the question.
- [What does this bit of papyrus say?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4585/what-does-this-bit-of-papyrus-say)
  I do not know whether this is a letter.
- [Who asked whom about the cape of parchment? And who answered?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4618/who-asked-whom-about-the-cape-of-parchment-and-who-answered)
  Is he referencing epistulae here? I think so, but am actually not sure.
- [What does “Filiane” mean?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/12852/what-does-filiane-mean)
  Epistulae is key to the translation. I think this should have the new tag attached to it.
- [Why did Cicero switch from “abs te” to “a te” in his later works?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/1251/why-did-cicero-switch-from-abs-te-to-a-te-in-his-later-works)
  I believe this question clearly should have the new tag, as the genre in which the writing happened, is one of the keys. I am unsure, though, as it is not about letter-writing specifically; letter-writing would be only one of the relevant genres.
- [Is “Heaven decreed better!” a correct translation for “Di melius!”](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/15185/is-heaven-decreed-better-a-correct-translation-for-di-melius)
  This would benefit from such a tag, but there is not room for any more. I do not know, though, what the purpose of having `sentence-translation` as a tag in and of itself, and not just a synonym.
- [Why is the Pluperfect Subjunctive used to Represent the Future in Cicero's “In Verrem” (2.2.162)?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/16320/why-is-the-pluperfect-subjunctive-used-to-represent-the-future-in-ciceros-in-v)
  For this question, it seems tangential, but the discussion of imperfect subjunctive in letters makes it relevant.
- [Can a “dative of agent” appear in an Ablative Absolute construction?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/12844/can-a-dative-of-agent-appear-in-an-ablative-absolute-construction)
  This already has five tags, but is there a point to having both `ablativus` and `ablativus-absolutus`? I think so, and I suppose that though letters are mentioned, it is not what the question really is about.

As an additional question, is this (posting it on meta) a better way to communicate a request such as this? It got completely lost in the chat – I never received a reply to [the question there](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58797174#58797174) – and as I understood the feedback from mod, posting it here was encouraged.

Comment: I think a good rule of thumb is not whether or not the Latin or English is found in a letter, but whether it's about the *language* of the letters or about the epistles/epistolary genre in general. Of course it should always be on a case-by-case basis. I also think re-tagging should be solely organic - if you see something and want to fix it, it can be fixed, but trawling to find examples makes a bit of a mess of things, especially if there isn't a clear consensus ahead of time.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the things mentioned below have already been brought up in chat or elsewhere, but I want to collect the points here in one place.

#### Retagging suggestions

To answer your additional question first:
If you have substantial tagging questions or suggestions, then asking on meta like this is the best way to go.
That way anyone who frequents meta can see the discussion and take part.

#### Tag edits in general

Adding a tag to a number of questions — or removing it — is a retagging operation.
No one should start such an operation without discussion.
A meta discussion is best, but a green light from a moderator in [our site's chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36130/conloqvivm) is also an option.

All edits bump the question to the top of the front page, or any page where people see recently active questions.
Those of us who use a page that shows all recent questions and answers will only see a flood of retagged stuff.
For that reason the suggested guideline is to **make only three edits per day**.

The comment by cmw above is excellent, and I agree that retagging should be organic.
If you see something in need of a fix, fix it, and try to look at it as a whole.
Retag, respell, or otherwise redo.
But do remember that it's not your post but someone else's, so polish only.

#### The name of the tag

I think the tag should have bee called [epistula](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/epistula).
The word *genus* had me puzzled.
Did you mean that it is a letter to one's family?
Then it occurred to me that you perhaps meant it to stand for "genre".

This is the trouble with translating tags to Latin.
While *genus* might indeed be the best Latin counterpart to "genre", it is not the same thing.
When I see the English word "genre", I think of classifying literature or similar arts.
When I see the Latin word *genus*, I think of familial relations.
The Latin word does not communicate like the English one does, and tags are all about communication.

But the whole word *genus* is best left out anyway.
Tags on our site or elsewhere on the network don't usually announce their "class".
No need to say that the tag is about "the genre of letters".
Just "letters" works fine.

We can have Latin versions of the tag name as synonyms, but I (and others, as votes suggest) prefer to [switch (almost) all our tags to English](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/546/79).
It seems likely that this tag will switch to English too, so at least having an English synonym now is a good idea.

#### The suggested questions

Let me go through your suggested questions for the tag:

> Letter-writing is relevant, but not key to the question.

Then don't add it.
It's pretty tangential.
If you're unsure about whether to edit, don't.

> I do not know whether this is a letter.

Then don't add it.
If you don't know it, then it is not very relevant for the question whether the source is a letter.
If no letters are mentioned and it wouldn't matter, why add the tag?

> Is he referencing epistulae here? I think so, but am actually not sure.

Then don't add it.
You can always ask for clarification, but again:
Would being related to a letter make a difference?

> Epistulae is key to the translation. I think this should have the new tag attached to it.

The question only has letters as an actor in a sentence.
I thought the tag was supposed to be about things like the language Cicero uses in his letters.
This question is not about letters at all.

> I believe this question clearly should have the new tag, as the genre in which the writing happened, is one of the keys. I am unsure, though, as it is not about letter-writing specifically; letter-writing would be only one of the relevant genres.

The tag would make sense here.
Letters are not the sole focus, but certainly part of it; the question's quote does mention "even in his letters".

> This would benefit from such a tag, but there is not room for any more. I do not know, though, what the purpose of having [sentence-translation](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sentence-translation) as a tag in and of itself, and not just a synonym.

If the tag you have in mind is not urgently needed, then it might be best not to override the OP's tagging decision.
The tag [sentence-translation](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sentence-translation) might in fact be on its way out, so a slot is likely to open.

The text is from the genre of letters, and the tag would make sense.
But as there's no hurry with it, I'd recommend waiting until things are clear with [sentence-translation](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sentence-translation).

> For this question, it seems tangential, but the discussion of imperfect subjunctive in letters makes it relevant.

The question is about a speech, not a letter.
That question could use clarifying tags, but the best ones would be [classical-latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classical-latin) and [cicero](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cicero) and [tenses](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tenses) and [consecutio-temporum](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/consecutio-temporum).
Those are what the question is about: the tenses and their sequence in the classical author Cicero.

In fact, the question is only tangentially about translation, so I would be tempted to create a new tag [pluperfect-tense](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pluperfect-tense) and add it in its place.

> This already has five tags, but is there a point to having both [ablativus](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ablativus) and [ablativus-absolutus](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ablativus-absolutus)? I think so, and I suppose that though letters are mentioned, it is not what the question really is about.

There is indeed a point to having both tags.
The question is about ablatives, and also about a common construction with the ablative (the AA).
Those are different things that people might want to look into, so both tags are well warranted.

The question is not about letters but the syntax of classical Latin.
There are far more important and descriptive tags, so I wouldn't retag it.

#### My suggestion

To collect things together, let me offer a concise suggestion.
The only one of the questions that could use the tag is [the one of Cicero's prepositions](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1251/79).
Go ahead and add a letter tag, but please call it [epistula](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/epistula) or [epistola](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/epistola) or [letter](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/letter) or a plural version of any of them.
We can then merge the older tag into it.
[The question on Cicero's tenses](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/16320/79) would indeed benefit from retagging, but letters have little to do with it.

Comment: Tag added as per your request. Thank you for providing a thorough ansewr; this will serve well as documentation for later.

Comment: @CannedMan Thanks! I synonymized the tags. I'll merge them later if no objections arise.